# Defining a subclass of owl:ObjectProperty with domains/range constraint

Tags: owl, ontology, rdfs

I am defining an ontology that contains several properties that share range/domain restrictions.

```
ns:synonym a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
  rdfs:range  ontolex:LexicalEntry .

ns:antoym a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
  rdfs:range  ontolex:LexicalEntry .

ns:meronym a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain ontolex:LexicalEntry ;
  rdfs:range  ontolex:LexicalEntry .

...
```

I would like to define a subclass of owl:ObjectProperty that will contain all these individual properties.

```
dbnary:NymProperty a rdfs:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf owl:ObjectProperty;
  <<where individuals has range XXX and domain YYY>> .

ns:synonym a dbnary:NymProperty.
ns:antoym a dbnary:NymProperty.
ns:meronym a dbnary:NymProperty.
...
```

Is it possible to do this in OWL ? What should I have instead of *<<where individuals has range XXX and domain YYY>>* ?

What is the impact (necessary reasoning, etc.) on the users of the ontology ?

I need this class of property to be defined as I would like to use these property individuals as range of another relation.

Comment: An OWL class represents a set of individuals and an OWL ObjectProperty a binary relation between 2 individuals. Hence, you cannot define a subclass of an ObjectProperty.

Comment: You can do whatever you want in RDF, but no standard OWL tool/reasoner will take this into account.

Comment: `dbnary:NymProperty rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ; owl:onProperty  rdfs:domain ; owl:hasValue ontolex:LexicalEntry]`, but see the snswer and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this in OWL ?

No, but yes.

## No because...

When someone asks if something can be expressed in OWL, they usually ask if it is allowed in an [OWL Ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#def_ontology), which is formally defined in the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Structural Specification and Functional-Style Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/). According to this specification, it is not possible to define a subclass of `owl:ObjectProperty`. Most tools that are described as "OWL tools", such as OWL editors (e.g., [Protégé](https://protege.stanford.edu/)) or OWL APIs (e.g., [the OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/)) or OWL reasoners (e.g., [HermiT](http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/)) are implementing this specification, which constrains what is allowed in an OWL ontology. In particular, not all RDF graphs can be processed correctly or completely by these tools.

## Yes because...

OWL, in its broader definition, comprises multiple standards, including the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language RDF-Based Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/) that defines the notion of an **OWL 2 Full ontology**, which is a synonym of **RDF Graph** but with the intention of interpreting it according to the RDF-based semantics of OWL. The RDF-based semantics gives a meaning to *any* RDF graph, including those that would not be valid representations of [OWL Ontologies](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#def_ontology). According to this formal semantics, it is possible to have subclasses of anything, including `owl:ObjectProperty`, which would match your requirements. However, the downside is that the RDF-based semantics is an undecidable logic. So the tools that are able to reason with OWL Full ontologies are incomplete. Some triplestore implement a partial axiomatisation of OWL RDF-based semantics, but some valid entailment cannot be derived with these tools.

Note that many existing ontologies do not match the requirements for being standard OWL 2 ontologies. Yet, they are simple enough to be used in many applications. Tools that implement the [RDFS semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdfs-interpretations) of the [RDF specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/) can be seen as simple, incomplete implementations of the OWL 2 RDF-based semantics. Some tools implement a superset of RDFS that can deal with more OWL constructs, but they are still incomplete.

With that said, it is generally ill-advised to use the `owl:` vocabulary in the definition of an RDF vocabulary, because the logical and practical consequences are hard to foresee. So use this kind of modelling responsibly.